# OutOfMemoryError on Google map Application Has lot of markers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

i am working on an application which has more then 10000 markers on google map , i am using google map v2 ,and as library android-maps-extensions https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/.
but when i load markers on map it make application slower and 10\5 times force close beacause of  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Exception.
all the markers have its own images , images loads form url, condition in which image is not loading  , defult image will be displat

is there any way to handle this kind of condition..?

Comment: You try to load 1000s `Bitmap`s into memory?

Comment: @MaciejGórski not but as per required...

Comment: Then how about posting the offending code as requested by Biraj Zalavadia? Not just directly posting your code, but finding exactly what causes `OutOfMemoryError` and posting the simplest code to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:largeHeap="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in order to request more memory from the Android's Virtual Machine.

Comment: but is it allow in 2.2 api ..?

Answer (score -1):

Use below code for your Image Loading.

Download jar from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

```
   private AQuery androidAQuery;
        androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);

    androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE URL, true, true,default icon(optional));
```

Comment: but @pratik it is about loading an image in imageview, this application loads many of images for displaying and also loads 1000 markers at a time so this make application slower and consume more memory , it cauase out of memory Exception, so is there any way to handle this condition.please read my question again and think on it. it is not only for loading an images..

Comment: Just try this, and see whats going on? Because we need to go for it step by step.

Comment: okay pratik i'll study AQuery and i am implemanting your suggestion in  my porject i need to change lot of code so i request to keep in touch,i'll contact soon.